# Only shows one computer name instead of many systems in servers.txt

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this simple script to get the services and the accounts that are running them.  My problem is that the data looks correct in the report but the server name does not change in the report.  Here is the code.

```
$servers = get-content C:\temp\servers.txt
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    Get-WmiObject win32_service | Select-Object -Property SystemName, DisplayName, startname | format-list -GroupBy startname | Out-File c:\temp\results.txt
}
```

Comment: You does not use `$server` variable inside `foreach` block.

Comment: Where would I use it to complete the foreach loop correctly?

Comment: Use `-append` in your output statement. `Out-File c:\temp\results.txt -append`

Comment: And `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server win32_service`.

Comment: Thanks Jan!  That is exactly what I needed.  IT worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.

```
$servers = get-content C:\temp\servers.txt
    foreach ($server in $servers)
    {
     Get-WmiObject win32_service -Computername $server | Select-Object -Property SystemName, DisplayName, startname | format-list -GroupBy startname | Out-File -append c:\temp\results.txt
    }
```

You can also use the following but note `SystemName` is not a property of Win32_Service.  To troubleshoot this, try using `Get-Service | Select -first 1 | Get-Member` will display the available attributes (sorry if this is the wrong term) with the important one being `MachineName`  thus replace SystemName for MachineName and you'll get the desired results.  Look up Hey Scripting Guy articles for further information.  For example, [this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/09/using-powershell-get-member-to-explore-the-net-framework.aspx)

```
gc .\Servers.txt | foreach {get-service -ComputerName $_ | `
Select-Object -Property MachineName, DisplayName, startname | `
format-list -GroupBy startname | Out-File -append c:\temp\results.txt}
```

Note, I'm using the backtick ` to make the command readable, paste into the Powershell ISE to save/run the script or just paste the lines into the console and press enter twice to run the multi-line script.